# How do I add a shortcode to a custom view without conflicts with the plugin in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I have created custom fields for my posts. One of them is "Widget" the widget field displays a widget based on its shortcode. I am using Toolset Plugin to create the template of the post. However when I pass the widget through the widget field, the template does not display it properly.

I assume the problem arises because Toolset relies heavily on shortcodes, and it gets confused when I add a different type of shortcode.

This only happens with custom fields, not the wordpress content field. There, it gets displayed properly through the template.

Thanks in advance if any of the know the solution and have come across a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add do_shortcode in your posts looping for showing data via custom fields.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Name of your field id')); ?>
```

here are essential links 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/